# Replicate Internal Promotion report in BigQuery with transactions

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Anyone have any success in replicating the Internal Promotions report from GA in BigQuery?

I'm looking for a report that incudes at a minimum the columns: date, promoName, promoPosition, promo_clicks, promo_views, transactions

As per (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014872?hl=en), the logic to attribute transactions looks rather complicated. Is this even possible or a good idea to bring in transactions in this report in BQ?

> "How transactions are attributed The Internal Promotion report
>   attributes transactions to either an internal-promotion click or
>   internal-promotion view.
>
> Each hit in an ecommerce session can have:
>
> 0 or 1 internal-promotion clicks 0 or more internal-promotion views
>   Internal-promotion click attribution If a hit includes a single
>   internal-promotion click, then that internal-promotion is credited for
>   the transaction.
>
> If a session includes multiple internal-promotion clicks, then the
>   last-clicked internal-promotion is credited for the transaction.
>
> If a hit includes zero internal-promotions clicks but one of that
>   user’s previous hits does include an internal-promotion click, then
>   the internal promotion from the previous click is credited for the
>   transaction.
>
> Internal-promotion view attribution If none of the conditions above is
>   true but a hit includes one or more internal-promotion views, then the
>   transaction is credited to all promotional views within the session."

Comment: Did you managed to do it ? I am facing the same issue

Comment: No unfortunately not. But client was understanding that it was a challenge to match up numbers exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understood your question, but the logic of the internal promotion attribution on GA it's not so complicated rather be tricky to implement. To track transaction attribution to the internal promotion you need to have the funnel of enhanced e-commerce implemented, not it all but at least checkout and purchase. If you have it, you need to make sure that your product data is consistently through the funnel. 
Promo attribution and list attribution are the only attributions you can get using enhanced ecommerce.

The best material that I found about enhanced e-commerce implementation is that [guide](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/enhanced-ecommerce-guide-for-google-tag-manager/). You'll find a lot of things about GTM and GA e ways to implement this kind of tracks.

Comment: Thanks, my goal is to replicate this report in Google BigQuery and not so much on the implementation side. So I meant it looks complicated in terms of recreating the report there in comparison to anything else I've encountered.

Comment: You could do that using UNNEST in subqueries. I've made one with information about e-commerce action and product data. This article helped me a lot https://towardsdatascience.com/https-medium-com-martin-weitzmann-bigquery-sql-on-nested-data-cf9589c105f4

Answer (score 1):

I managed to replicate the Internal Promotions but only with the last promotion clicked attribution. Since my client doesn't have promotion on the purchase page, I have not bothered adding the attribution by promotion view to the query. However it can be added by querying the transactions hits with promotion name.

The logic I used is this one :

1. Get all the views and clicks for each promotion (table promotion_views_and_clicks)
2. Get all the session ids that clicked on each promotion (table session_with_promotion_click)
3. From the previous query, get the last promotion id clicked by each session (table last_promotion_click)
4. Get the session ids with a transaction ids and the revenue linked to it (table session_with_transaction)
5. Combine the views and clicks for each promotion and the transactions data based on the session ids from step 3, filtering on the transactions that happened after a promotion click

Here is my code :

```
WITH 
promotion_views_and_clicks AS (
    SELECT
        promo.promoName AS promotion_name,
        COUNT(hit.promotionActionInfo.promoIsView) AS views,
        COUNT(hit.promotionActionInfo.promoIsClick) AS clicks,
    FROM
        YOUR_DATA,
        UNNEST(hits) AS hit,
        UNNEST(hit.promotion) AS promo
    GROUP BY
        promotion_name),

session_with_promotion_click AS (
    SELECT
        promo.promoName AS promotion_name,
        concat(fullvisitorid, cast(visitstarttime AS string), date) AS sessionid,
        hit.time AS time,
    FROM
        `YOUR_DATA`,
        UNNEST(hits) AS hit,
        UNNEST(hit.promotion) AS promo
    WHERE
        totals.visits = 1 
        AND hit.promotionActionInfo.promoIsClick is true
    GROUP BY promotion_name, sessionid, time),

last_promotion_click AS (
    SELECT
        a.*
    FROM session_with_promotion_click a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN session_with_promotion_click b 
    ON (a.sessionid = b.sessionid AND a.time < b.time)
    WHERE b.sessionid IS NULL),

session_with_transaction AS (
    SELECT
        concat(fullvisitorid, cast(visitstarttime AS string), date) AS sessionid,
        hit.time AS time,
        hit.transaction.transactionId AS transactionid,
        sum(hit.transaction.transactionrevenue)/1000000 AS revenue
    FROM
        `YOUR_DATA`,
        UNNEST(hits) AS hit
    WHERE
        totals.visits = 1
        AND hit.transaction.transactionid is not null
    GROUP BY sessionid, time,transactionid)

SELECT 
    promotion_views_and_clicks.promotion_name,
    promotion_views_and_clicks.views,
    promotion_views_and_clicks.clicks,
    ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(promotion_views_and_clicks.clicks, promotion_views_and_clicks.views),4)*100 AS promotion_CTR, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT session_with_transaction.transactionid) AS transactions,
    ROUND(SUM(session_with_transaction.revenue),2) AS revenue,
    ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(COUNT(DISTINCT session_with_transaction.transactionid), promotion_views_and_clicks.clicks),4)*100 AS promotion_CVR
FROM promotion_views_and_clicks
    LEFT JOIN last_promotion_click ON promotion_views_and_clicks.promotion_name = last_promotion_click.promotion_name
    LEFT JOIN session_with_transaction ON last_promotion_click.sessionid = session_with_transaction.sessionid
    AND session_with_transaction.time >= last_promotion_click.time
GROUP BY promotion_name, views, clicks
ORDER BY views DESC
```