# BigQuery - Transactions in internal promo report

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

like in the question here ([Replicate Internal Promotion report in BigQuery with transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61093854/replicate-internal-promotion-report-in-bigquery-with-transactions)) I want to rebuild the internal promo report from Google Analytics.
I was able to get PromoViews and PromoClicks, but I don't get the transactions...

My query looks like this

```
SELECT  
          clientid,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitstarttime,
          concat(fullvisitorid, cast(visitstarttime AS string)) AS sessionid,
          hp.promoid,
          hp.promoname,
          hp.promocreative
          hp.promoposition,
          promotionActionInfo.promoIsView as promoview,
          promotionActionInfo.promoIsClick as promoclick
          
FROM [MYDATA], UNNEST (hits) as h, UNNEST (h.promotion) as hp
```

When I sum *promoview* and *promoclick* I get the exact same results like in Google Analytics
The official Google Documentation says:

```
>How transactions are attributed
>The Internal Promotion report attributes transactions to either an internal-promotion click or >internal-promotion view.
>
>Each hit in an ecommerce session can have:
>
>0 or 1 internal-promotion clicks
>0 or more internal-promotion views
>Internal-promotion click attribution
>If a hit includes a single internal-promotion click, then that internal-promotion is credited >for the transaction.
>
>If a session includes multiple internal-promotion clicks, then the last-clicked internal->promotion is credited for the transaction.
>
>If a hit includes zero internal-promotions clicks but one of that user’s previous hits does >include an internal-promotion click, then the internal promotion from the previous click is >credited for the transaction.
>
>Internal-promotion view attribution
>If none of the conditions above is true but a hit includes one or more internal-promotion >views, then the transaction is credited to all promotional views within the session.
```

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014872?hl=en

Keeping this in mind, my approach was to do a join with a separate table where I query the enhanced ecommerce data using *sessionid* as the join key

```
SELECT
          clientid,
          fullvisitorid,
          visitstarttime,
          concat(fullvisitorid, cast(visitstarttime AS string)) AS sessionid,
          hp.v2ProductName AS ProductName,
          h.transaction.transactionId AS TransactionId,
          hp.productQuantity as Quantity,
FROM [MYDATA], UNNEST (hits) AS h, UNNEST (h.product) as hp
WHERE 
h.eCommerceAction.action_type = "6" AND 
(hp.isImpression IS NULL) AND
(
  (h.promotionActionInfo.promoIsView is true) OR 
  (h.promotionActionInfo.promoIsClick is true)
)
```

But it seems that my WHERE clause (filtering the promoviews and clicks) is not working like I expect, because I receive an empty table as a result.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Did you managed doing it ? I am facing the exactly same problem